# Computing the Geometric Mean of positive random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, means

So I have a sequence of positive random variables, and I know that $E(|\log X_k|) < \infty$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

I'm trying to compute $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\prod_{k=1}^n X_k\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$.  So the most obvious thing I thought of to do was:

that $$\log\left( \left(\prod_{k=1}^n X_k\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\log(X_k)}{n} \implies E\left( \log\left(\left( \prod_{k=1}^n X_k\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)\right) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{E(\log X_k)}{n}.$$ Since $\log X_k \in L^1((\Omega,\mathcal{F},P))$, it follows that the summation of the righthand side makes sense. Now since the $X_k$'s are i.i.d, it follows that $E(\log X_k) = \mu < \infty$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.  Hence, we conclude: $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{E(\log X_k)}{n} = \mu\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n} = \mu.$$ Thus, since $E$ is linear (and hence continuous) and $\log$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$, we conclude that: $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E\left( \log\left(\left( \prod_{k=1}^n X_k\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)\right) = E\left( \log\left(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(  \prod_{k=1}^n X_k\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)\right) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{E(\log X_k)}{n} = \mu.$$

So now I have $E(\log(\boldsymbol{X})) = \mu =E(\log(X_k))$ for $\boldsymbol{X} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\prod_{k=1}^n X_k \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$.  I'm not sure what to do from here.

I know that what I'm looking for is $e^{\mu} = e^{E(\log(X_k))}$ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, but I don't see how I can remove the expected value to conclude that $$\log(\boldsymbol{X}) = \mu \implies \boldsymbol{X} = e^\mu.$$

Comment: Presumably you have i.i.d. random variables. If $Y_k=\log(X_k)$ and $E[Y_k]$ is finite then you have  $\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n Y_k$ converging to  $\mathbb E[Y_k]$ in a law of large numbers sense.  This then gives you $\left(\prod\limits_{k=1}^n X_k\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ converging to $e^{\mathbb E[\log(X_k)]}$ in the same sense

Comment: Great, thank you!  After looking at my class course calendar, we cover the LLN tomorrow, so I guess working ahead can be tedious at times.